# В приложениях перестали работать gms сервисы

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services, android-gradle

При `gradle sync` или `build` в любом приложении с gms в консоли показывается это:

> Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/bytheway/debug, src/debug/bytheway, src/bytheway, src/debug, src/bythewayDebug]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>   Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/bytheway/release, src/release/bytheway, src/bytheway, src/release, src/bythewayRelease]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

Гугл вход не работает, гугл места не показываетактивити автокомплейта, фиребейс не пускает в БД. И это случается в каждом приложении и началось приблезительно 2 недели назад. Код запускал тот-же. На компе юсернейм без кирилици

Comment: А вы файл google-services.json в проект добавили?

Comment: @Suvitruf конечно

Comment: видимо, не туда добавили, раз `could not find`

Comment: Проверьте подключение плагина, без него обычно такая проблема

Comment: @Jarvis_J Туда я добавил

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei подключён правильно

Comment: Я в анддроид разработке уже год.

Answer (score 0):

> Это происходит, когда вы используете какой-либо сервис связанный с
>   firebase, и вы не поместили файл google-services.json, который нам
>   нужен для использования службы.
>
> Решение состоит в том, что вам нужно получить файл с консоли firebase,
>   и вам нужно поместить его в папку уровня вашего приложения, если вы
>   создаете один проект в консоли для всех flavor, и если вы создаете
>   другой, вам нужно создать номер файлов для нескольких проектов или
>   flavors.

*ответ взят - [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47565761/gradle-warnings-could-not-find-google-services-json-while-looking-in)*

Основная идея:

1. Проверьте месторасположение файла `google-services.json`, возможно
   он неверный.
2. Проверьте есть ли этот `google-services.json` во всех **Product
   Flavor(s)**. Может быть такое что в одной из них файл отсутствует.
3. Сгенерируйте `google-services.json` по возможности заново и
   замените во всех местах.

Возможно файл изменялся или перемещался.

*p.s.: если найдете, что проблема не в этом. Пожалуйста напишите о том как решили.*

Comment: Почему вы не прочитали комментарий, в котором я уже написал, что он есть в каждой папке флавоюрсов?

Comment: я прочитал, просто в магию не верю)

Comment: У вас есть контроль версий на проекте?

Comment: Конечно есть. Но эта версия работала несколько недель назад, откат не должен помочь.

Comment: Вы можете вспомнить конкретный день, когда все пошло не так и посмотреть коммиты за сутки?

Comment: Такая возможность отсутствует. Тем более это почти со ВСЕМИ проектами. В одном есть только пуши и они рботают, но в билде всё-ровно показывается это сообщение.

Comment: Что бы вы правилльно понимали, проектыы не мои, я просто рядовой разработчик. Файлы созданы правильно и разными людьми.

Comment: Хорошо. Вы согласны что gms сервисами пользуетесь не только вы? У меня в том числе они есть и активно используются во всем приложении. На SO нет 100 вопросов "помогите gms упал". Возможно логично было предположить что проблема пока наблюдается только у вас. Вы сказали, что работаете над проектом не один. Возможно такое что кто-то переместил файл google-services.json или изменил его, может случайно может не случайно. Не вы, но тот кто еще работает? Если такое реально невозможно, создайте тестовый проект и подключите сервисы gms. Логично, что если они будут работать, то это не косяк Google?

Comment: Попробуйте сгенерировать новый google-services.json файл, если это возможно и подставить его. Ну вдруг поможет, сейчас пока других вариантов нет, верно?

Comment: Хотя со всеми проектами, да, это странно. А файл google-services.json для всех проектов общий или свой?

Comment: вот еще статья https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/could-not-find-google-services-json-while-looking-in-src-nullnull-debug-src-debug-nullnull-src-nullnull-src-debug-src-nullnulldebug/126299

Comment: попробуйте вот это сделать https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-solve-this-issue/26549

Comment: тоже самое советуют https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-android/issues/1684

Comment: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. - вот это сделайте

Comment: я уже загружал  файл с сервера. Файлы разные, это точно, для каждого проекта - уникальный.